# Code Sign Application option

Tags: xcode, code-signing

What does "Signature - Code Sign Application" option checkbox in Summary panel of application Targets in Xcode 4.5 is needed for?
Isn't it the magic option which eliminates all this codesigning headache when distributing the application?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike iOS apps, desktop apps don't need to be signed to run on a machine. Turning this on means that you will be using code signing.

If you are distributing through the Mac App store you will need to sign your app with an Apple Certificate.

If you are distributing your app yourself you have the choice of signing your app with an Apple certificate or not. Although there are settings on Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8) which can be set up to only allow apps that are signed (or even only allow apps that are from the Mac App store).

So no. The checkbox doesn't remove the "headache" of codesigning, it just turns the option on or off.